# a space isomorphic to $S^{p+q}$

Tags: general-topology, compactness

In one of the paper I have met that 
$$\mathbb{S}^{p+q} \cong \mathbb{S}^p \times \mathbb{R}^q \cup \mathbb{S}^{p-1}$$

I don't know how to deal with $\mathbb{S}^{p-1}$ sphere.

Are there any reference to this isomorphism?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by constant curvature? Which metric are you using?

Comment: @ArcticChar $S^{p,q}$ denote the quadric $\{v \in \mathbb{R}^{p+q+1}: Q(v) = 1\}$ where $Q(x_1,..,x_{p+1},y_1,...,y_q) = x_1^2+...+x_{p+1}^2 - y_1^2-...-y_q^2$.

Comment: @ArcticChar but I have troubles with $\mathbb{S}^{p+q} \cong \mathbb{S}^p \times \mathbb{R}^q \cup \mathbb{S}^{p-1}$

Comment: I am a bit confused since you mentioned curvature. For the isomorphism $\cong$, do you mean a topological isomorphism or something more?

Comment: @ArcticChar so sorry, I just mentioned the curvature as some extra thing. I just need topological isomorphism. I updated the question!

Comment: It is unclear what means “$\cup \mathbb{S}^{p-1}$”. If it means a topological sum, then the RHS should denote a disconnected space, whereas RHS should denote a connected space. If it means that we somehow attach $\cup \mathbb{S}^{p-1}$ to the other space then how this attachment was made?

Comment: @AlexRavsky that's what I was asking for.